# jQuery .click(), avoid reacting on certain element?

Tags: jquery, click, text-editor

I'm creating a texteditor (CKEditoR) dynamically using javascript when a doubleClick event occurs on certain elements. The editor is closed whenever a click occurs outside of the editor and the content is saved. The problem I just noticed is that since I'm using a toolbar for the editor in another element, the editor gets closed when clicking on the toolbar which has the 'Bold'-function etc.

```
$('html').click(function() {
    if (editor)
        toggleEditor(activeSid);
});
```

It works fine when clicking inside the editor etc, but since I'm using another div for the toolbar, toggleEditor() is called when clicking on the toolbar. So how can I avoid this method to be called if a click occurs in the editor OR the toolbar-div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to exclude some elements you can use the `:not()` selector:

```
$("div:not('#yourToolbarDiv')").click(function() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm. However, is it possible to combine this with 'html' or something? It doesn't react right now when clicking outside the wrapper.

Comment: sure it's possible - you can define as many selectors as you wish separated by commas, e.g. `$("html, div1, div2, div:not('#yourToolbarDiv')")`